# React root component does not load the entire index.html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, node.js, reactjs

I'm new using reactjs. I have a template where I need to load in the head some css and at the end of the body, I need to load some js libraries and plugins, but this last part doesn't work. Let me show you how looks my index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" name="viewport" />
    <meta content="" name="description" />
    <meta content="" name="author" />
    <link href="assets/plugins/jquery-ui/themes/base/minified/jquery-ui.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="assets/plugins/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="assets/plugins/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="assets/plugins/ionicons/css/ionicons.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="assets/css/animate.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="assets/css/style.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="assets/css/style-responsive.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="assets/css/theme/default.css" rel="stylesheet" id="theme" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/plugins/gritter/css/jquery.gritter.css" />
    <script src="assets/plugins/pace/pace.min.js"></script>
    <link href="assets/plugins/isotope/isotope.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="assets/plugins/lightbox/css/lightbox.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="assets/plugins/pace/pace.min.js"></script>

    <title>Nautam Manager</title>
</head>
<body id="nbody">

<div id="root">
    <div id="page-loader" class="fade in"><span class="spinner"></span></div>
</div>
<!-- ================== BEGIN BASE JS ================== -->
<script src="assets/plugins/jquery/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="assets/plugins/jquery/jquery-migrate-1.1.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="assets/plugins/jquery-ui/ui/minified/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="assets/plugins/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
<script src="assets/crossbrowserjs/html5shiv.js"></script>
<script src="assets/crossbrowserjs/respond.min.js"></script>
<script src="assets/crossbrowserjs/excanvas.min.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
<script src="assets/plugins/slimscroll/jquery.slimscroll.min.js"></script>
<script src="assets/plugins/jquery-cookie/jquery.cookie.js"></script>
<script src="assets/plugins/gritter/js/jquery.gritter.js"></script>
<!-- ================== END BASE JS ================== -->

<!-- ================== BEGIN PAGE LEVEL JS ================== -->
<script src="assets/plugins/isotope/jquery.isotope.min.js"></script>
<script src="assets/plugins/lightbox/js/lightbox.min.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/gallery.demo.min.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/apps.min.js"></script>
<!-- ================== END PAGE LEVEL JS ================== -->
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        App.init();
        Gallery.init();
    });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

In my root div tag is where I'm going to render my react app, but after run it and check the HTML generated I can see that the import for all js libs was not loaded.

After that, in my Root component I added each script tag manually using document.createElement('script') and populating it, but everytime the DOM is updated, the script part disapear.

Can you give me some advise about how can I do this or what is the best way to solve this problem?

Please let me know if you need me to share more info?

Regards

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to import the js file in your React components instead of load js in your html page.

You can try https://github.com/shaneosullivan/ReactDependentScript/

I've used this plugin every time i need to import external js into my react component. You can try the example given.